# Definition of differentiability classes

Tags: real-analysis

A common way to define differentiability classes is as follows: a function from an open set in a Euclidean space to a Euclidean space is of class $C^k$ if its partial derivatives of order, up to and including, $k$ (exist and) are continuous. Is it the same to say that such a function is of class $C^k$ if its $k$th order derivative (exists and) is continuous? (One can make sense of higher-order derivatives by defining the derivative in the context of normed linear spaces.)

Answer (score 1):

Yes, they are the same and it is also possible to define partial derivatives of functions on arbitrary normable spaces.

Let $V_1,...,V_n,W$ be normable spaces. Then, $\prod_{i=1}^n V_i$ is also normable. The natural norm would be $||\cdot||_p= \sum_{i=1}^n ||\cdot||_{V_i}$. Now consider a function $f:\prod_{i=1}^n V_i \rightarrow W$.

> 1.$f$ is k-times Fréchet differentiable and $D^k f$ is continuous
>
> 2. $f$ has partial derivatives of order $k$ and each partial detivatives are continuous
> 3. $f$ is Gâteaux differentiable and $f_G^{(k)}$ is continous.

1,2,3 are all equivalent. For a concerete explanation, see "Cartan-Differential Calculus"

Answer (score 0):

Yes. Suppose that $f^{(k)}$ is continuous at $x$, but for some $j < k$, the function $f^{(j)}$ does not exist or is not continuous at $x$. In the former case, then $f^{(j + 1)} (x) = \lim_{h \to \infty} \frac{f^{(j)}(x + h) - f^{(j)}(x)}{h}$ does not exist because $f^{(j)}(x)$ does not exist, and the latter is impossible because a function cannot be discontinuous at a point and still be differentiable there (a standard result). But then by this, we have that $f^{(j + 2)}, f^{(j + 3)}$, and on and on until $f^{(k)}$ do not exist.